# How Linux manage memory when doing IO

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls, mmap

In my point of view, when we read a file by calling open and then read system call, the content of the file in disk will firstly be read in kernel space and then copy to user space or the process, so, if the file is big file like 1G, read will occupy 2G memory in physical memory, 1G maps to kernel space, and 1G maps to the process. I know this may be wrong, but Where am I wrong? How Linux manage memory in situation like reading a file? If I use mmap instead of read, then how the Linux deal with it differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the file is big file like 1G, read will occupy 2G memory in physical memory, 1G maps to kernel space, and 1G maps to the process.

No, this assumption is wrong.

Dependent on filesystem, kernel may read file on, e.g., 4K portions (one page).

When user requests 1G bytes via `read` system call, kernel may copy to user buffer only 4K portion of the file, and return number of bytes have been read. After that user may repeat `read` syscall with adjusted size and buffer address.

> If I use mmap instead of read, then how the Linux deal with it differently?

In case of `mmap` reading every 4K block from the file may be deffered until this block will be **actually accessed** by the user.

This follows general interpretation of *user* memory: user operates with **virtual** memory, which should be **mapped** to the *physical* one **only when accessed**.

Comment: Will read system call copy data from kernel space to user space?

Comment: Then if I read a 1G file, all the file content must be copied to kernel, but these 1G content won't all be in kernel space, kernel will release some blocks at times, whole content of file can only be in user space, am I right?

Comment: `whole content of file can only be in user space` - Almost true. Some part of content could be swapped.

Comment: Is "these 1G content won't all be in kernel space, kernel will release some blocks at times" right?

Comment: Yes, kernel may release (forget) some blocks it has read before.

Comment: Then, one last question, could you please explain "Some part of content could be swapped", In my point of view,this is for memory saving, so if the process access the content which is swapped, then, what will happen?

Comment: Yes, swapping is for memory saving. When swapped virtual memory will be accessed, its content will be automatically restored from the swap.